# windows 10 showing as freedos on grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, grub4dos

I dual booted ubuntu with windows 10 but on the Grub boot menu, window 10 supposed option is showing as FREEDOS. While booting to my ubuntu is fine, booting to my windows through the freedos is not . It brings up a 1s screen and returns to the grub menu. Trying to inspect my partion in Ubuntu, Every partion is mountable and all files are fine. Booting into my windows is the problem. Any help ?

Comment: Were you previously dual booting Windows and FreeDOS?

Comment: I suppose the system came with no OS and windows 10 was installed on it by the first user. Don't know if the answer is a yes or no.

Comment: Use the `Disks` program to examine your disk partitions. Are any of them marked as 'Windows' and NTFS?

Comment: /dev/sda2 * 16779264 33556479 16777216 8G c W95 FAT32 (LBA).......this is showing as freedos but the boot files are on the /dev/sda2

Comment: `/dev/sda3` looks like a possible Windows partition.

Comment: @Baseman please don't put command output in the comments, instead edit them into the original question, and format them properly.

Comment: Are you using a Windows installation that *somebody else installed*?  I strongly advise against this. It could contain malicious software (even if the previous owner did not explicitly install it deliberately).  It's best practice to format/erase a used device before using it.  Perhaps this is a good opportunity to install both operating systems cleanly and safely.  Windows should be installed first.  Leave some unpartitioned free space for Ubuntu, be consistent with UEFI booting and the installation should be easy and problem free.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Grub Customizer](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) to edit your boot menu.

Open a terminal and

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`

If you do have a Windows installation, it will detect it and allow you to add it to the boot menu.